# Why does a Tulsi leaf always fall with the dark side down?

Tags: everyday-life, probability

[image]

When it comes to tossing a coin in Kerala, Tulsi leaves are considered to be a good substitute for coins. Or at least they say it is!

It just occured to me long ago that my mother tossed a tulsi leaf to decide whether or not to send me for a class excursion. And she won, my picnic was canceled. She did this trick with me many times henceforth and I discovered that I was the unluckiest person in the world.

Today, out of a random thought, I experimented with tulsi leaves to test their validity as luck measuring instrument. To my surprise, each throw gave the same result; the darker side down!

How do I explain it? Maybe more chlorophyll makes one side heavier!

Anyway, SHE knew it all along!

Comment: I think a likely candidate is aerodynamic effects, due to the shape of the leaf, which causes one direction to be more aerodynamically stable than the other. It would be difficult to verify this though, without knowing more about the detailed geometry of the leaf.

Comment: @Time4Tea I made a paper replica of the leaf and tried it. It gave the same results. You must be right! The inward curve of the leaf may be the reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I flipped a margarine packet lid seven times. It landed with the convex part facing down all seven times. I theorise that with the concave face downward (the "empty parachute" position), it is in unstable equilibrium, the air resistance increases, there is turbulence around the edges, and the chances of flipping increase, but with the convex face downward (the "falling boat" position), the air resistance decreases, it is in stable equilibrium, and it tends to land that way.